# Check file size in Groovy script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I use `Groovy` script in `SoapUI` to list all the files from a given directory. I use this code to filter empty files.

```
dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) {
    if(file.length() > 0){file ->
        list << file
    }
}
```

I got following error message:

> org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: Script8.groovy: 16: expecting '}', found '->' @ line
>   16, column 29. if(file.length() > 0){file -> ^
>   org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: expecting '}', found '->'
>   @ line 16, column 29. at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:143)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:111)
>   at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:237)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:167)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:931)
>   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:593)
>   at

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can't use closure in `if` operation

there should be usual begin-end of block :

```
if(file.length() > 0){
    list << file
}
```